# Insert JSON values and ignore duplicate keys/conflicts

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

My SP below handles receiving a list of Identifiers in JSON, unpacking the values and inserting them into the table. However I want to ensure that the values are unique. I have a unique index set called "UniqueListing" with columns `Identifier` and `URL` set on them.

I want to make sure that only the IDs that are unique are inserted and nothing is done to the already existing values. I also want to ensure they aren't returned as a part of the response.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "RecordProcessingList" (
  "@Identifiers" JSON,
  "@Source"      VARCHAR(25)
)
RETURNS TABLE (
  "ID"         UUID,
  "Identifier" VARCHAR(50)
) AS
$func$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY
  INSERT INTO
    "Listings" AS l (
      "ID",
      "Identifier",
      "Source",
      "URL",
      "Checksum",
      "Status"
    )
  (
    SELECT
      UUID_GENERATE_V4(),
      key::TEXT,
      "@Source",
      TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM value::TEXT)::TEXT AS value,
      '',
      'PROCESSING'
    FROM
      JSON_EACH("@Identifiers")
  )
  ON CONFLICT (
    "Identifier"
  )
  DO NOTHING
  RETURNING
    l."ID",
    l."Identifier";
END;
$func$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you need to add

```
ON CONFLICT (
  "Identifier","URL"
)
DO NOTHING
```

Comment: So when I add in URL the query complains about the column being too vague. If I attempt specifying an alias such as l then the column cannot be found. :-/